# selenium - how to click on hyperlink without href or onclick

Tags: selenium, hyperlink

as part of a black box testing I get to a link

```
<a id="tpn_4163628" style="color:#00F;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;"></a>
```

and have ho clue how to simulate a click since there is no href nor onclick.

any ideas?

Comment: Whats the use of this hyperlink as it wont be visible on screen?

Comment: Use a CSS or xpath selector on the ID. You don't say which language you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ID where the first part is always the same, you can use a CSS selector to match it.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[id^='tpn_']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an ID, so this should do the trick:

```
selenium.click("tpn_4163628");
```

This is for Java, C# and Selenium IDE, if you use other languages, please read http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/03/the-selenium-click-command/ for more info.

Comment: as mentioned this is a blackbox testing, the id is generated per object so tpn_4163628 is an example. I do know there is a prefix "tpn_" but don't know the following number. Is there a way to extract that or to go by id contains?

Comment: ok, I didn't know you meant that with blackbox testing. 1st option is to adjust the html, but if you're not able to do so, is there some kind of unique parent element you can select on?